# terraform, azurerm, and chef extension

Tags: azure, terraform

Provisioning a regular-old VM with AzureRM provisioner, trying to get the Chef extension installed.   Terraform plan is barfing at me regarding my settings section.   The Chef extension requires settings that are actually embedded key-value pairs, like the following.

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

```
settings = <<SETTINGS
  "bootstrap_options": {
      "chef_node_name": "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}",
      "chef_server_url": "<url>",
      "validation_client_name": "<validator>"
  }
  "runlist": "my_starting_runlist"
SETTINGS
```

Answer (score 0):

shoot...it was a comma after the bootstrap_options.   argh.....